Unable to define/use my own macro on HLSL Unity3D
I defined a macro like: #define UNITY_SAMPLE_TEX2DARRAY_GRAD(tex, coord, dx, dy) tex.SampleGrad(sampler##tex, coord, dx, dy) to be used on this code:
fixed3 textureArrayNoTileNormal( UNITY_ARGS_TEX2DARRAY(texArray), in NoTileUVs ntuvs, in half normalScale )
{
    // Use modified UVs to sample a normal map, also inverting red and green channels where needed due to mirroring
    return lerp( lerp( fixed3( ntuvs.ofa.z, ntuvs.ofa.w, 1 ) * UnpackNormalWithScale( UNITY_SAMPLE_TEX2DARRAY_GRAD( UNITY_PASS_TEX2DARRAY(texArray), ntuvs.uva, ntuvs.ddxa, ntuvs.ddya ), normalScale ),
                       fixed3( ntuvs.ofb.z, ntuvs.ofb.w, 1 ) * UnpackNormalWithScale( UNITY_SAMPLE_TEX2DARRAY_GRAD( UNITY_PASS_TEX2DARRAY(texArray), ntuvs.uvb, ntuvs.ddxb, ntuvs.ddyb ), normalScale ), ntuvs.b.x ),
                 lerp( fixed3( ntuvs.ofc.z, ntuvs.ofc.w, 1 ) * UnpackNormalWithScale( UNITY_SAMPLE_TEX2DARRAY_GRAD( UNITY_PASS_TEX2DARRAY(texArray), ntuvs.uvc, ntuvs.ddxc, ntuvs.ddyc ), normalScale ),
                       fixed3( ntuvs.ofd.z, ntuvs.ofd.w, 1 ) * UnpackNormalWithScale( UNITY_SAMPLE_TEX2DARRAY_GRAD( UNITY_PASS_TEX2DARRAY(texArray), ntuvs.uvd, ntuvs.ddxd, ntuvs.ddyd ), normalScale ), ntuvs.b.x ), ntuvs.b.y );
}

The following error prompts: Unexpected token '('. Expected one of: ',' ')' at Assets/Resources/Shaders/Terrain/textureNoTile.cginc(93)
I have two questions:

Can I see the character position where the errors occur? on Unity3D)
I understand that is caused because tex.SampleGrad isn't allowed,
but why? 'm running under DX11.

Also, behind the code above I have these conditions:
#if defined(SHADER_API_D3D11) || defined(SHADER_API_XBOXONE) || defined(SHADER_API_GLES3) || defined(SHADER_API_GLCORE)
    #define UNITY_SAMPLE_TEX2DARRAY_GRAD(tex, coord, dx, dy) tex.SampleGrad(sampler##tex, coord, dx, dy)
#else
    #if defined(UNITY_COMPILER_HLSL2GLSL) || defined(SHADER_TARGET_SURFACE_ANALYSIS)
        #define UNITY_SAMPLE_TEX2DARRAY_GRAD(tex, coord, dx, dy) tex2DArray(tex, coord, dx, dy)
    #endif
#endif

But if I use this code, then I'm unable to use the function because the undeclared identifier UNITY_SAMPLE_TEX2DARRAY_GRAD error prompts, why? Don't I meet any of the defined preprocessor directives? How can I check them in Unity3D?
